# Pushing an empty file instead of another to github

Tags: json, git, github

I have a local repository with a *config.json* file which contains sensible configuration data. This file follows a schema found in *config.json.template*. The two files look like these (not actual content):

**config.json.template**

```
{
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
}
```

**config.json**

```
{
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "123456789"
}
```

Instead of placing the *config.json* in my .gitignore, is there a way to replace it with *config.json.template* at push-time? So that my repository will contain a *config.json* file that just needs to be filled out by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off pushing just the template file and not a file that you want people to modify.  People working with your repository won't appreciate having a tracked file that they must modify, since it means that `git checkout` and other operations will sometimes require them to stash first and then unstash.

In general, files that are intended to be modified on a per-user basis, like configuration files or editor files, shouldn't be saved directly in version control.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply push **config.json.template** as it is.

Comment: Of course I could, I was just wondering if there was any alternative